# Rails Multi Table Inheritance, Polymorphic association or Single Table Inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, data-modeling, openehr

I'm trying to implement the OpenEHR reference model in Rails (ActiveRecord), but I'm finding some problems, since it works with a lot of different of different classess,

Here is the diagram of a [Composition](http://www.openehr.org/local/releases/1.0.1/uml/Browsable/_9_0_76d0249_1109090397344_693008_8499Report.html):

[image: Composition diagram]

As you can see, a lot of classes "inherit" a couple of attributes from `Locatable` or `Pathable`* (the whole reference is huge, and almost every class inherit from it).

Also, it establish data_types as other classes, for example in the same composition class, `language` is class `CODE_PHRASE`, that have two attributes ([link](http://www.openehr.org/local/releases/1.0.1/uml/Browsable/_9_0_76d0249_1109068253492_817483_4348Report.html)).

Therefore I encounter two problems 1) how can I inherit attributes from abstract classes, and 2) how is that I can "include" the needed "classes".

For the first problem I thought in using Polymorphic Associations.

For the second one, I thought using STI, but I'm quickly finding a lot of almost similar models (they are exactly the same actually): `CompositionLanguage`, `CompositionTerritory`, `EntrySetting`, `EntryEncoding` that I only use in the `type` attribute to "link back", for example: The composition class, can have up to three attributes with `CODE_PHRASE`, since all three references a different attribute (language, territory and category), I thought that I needed to know for the associations (there's no point in knowing that Composition has 3 code_phrases, but I didn't know which one is the corresponding attribute).  On the other hand, the `Entry` class, have the `setting` and `encoding` attribute ([link](http://www.openehr.org/local/releases/1.0.1/uml/Browsable/_9_0_76d0249_1109066119163_537311_2210Report.html)).

I realize that there could be different approaches, but I would really like to know if that maybe Rails (or ActiveRecord), wasn't made for this. Or, maybe I'm missing conceptual info.

Answer (score 5):

The openEHR RM specification has deeply nested inheritance and composite patterns with tree hierarchy.

I could not implement this nested inheritance by ActiveRecord. The following implementation is an example to simulate openEHR RM.
I would be very happy if this example could help you.

https://github.com/skoba/openehr_rm_rails

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this project ..
https://github.com/skoba/openehr-rails

I think Shinji uses Active Record.

Personally, given the complex structure of the openEHR RM, if I was starting out I might look to use something like MongoDB with an ORM.

I have pointed the openehr technical community to your question via the openehr technical list to see if others can help.

Ian